# HTML5 Video not always loading videos

Tags: angular, html, typescript, html5-video

I have a page with two video players,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">

      <video width="520" height="440" #mainV  controls [src]="CameraDataUrl">
    <canvas #captureCanvas ></canvas>
  </video>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">

      <video width="320" height="240" #subV  controls [src]="DashDataUrl"></video>

    </div>

  </div>
```

the source is taken from a TypeScript class:

```
this.GetCameraInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.camera != null) {
        this.CameraDataUrl = "data:video/mp4;base64," + this.camera;
        clearInterval(this.GetCameraInterval);    
      }
    }, 100);

    this.GetDashInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.dash != null) {
        this.DashDataUrl = "data:video/mp4;base64," + this.dash;
        clearInterval(this.GetDashInterval);
      }
    }, 100);
```

I set a Timeout of 2.5 seconds before displaying the page to make sure the url of each video is getting the address from Redux (and also prints them to the console, so I can see they are not null),
but the video not always loads(sometimes both of them are not loading, sometimes one, sometimes they both ok. but they always get the address of the video).
[image: example]

What can cause it, and how should I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: What is the reason for the `setInterval`?

Comment: To keep checking the Redux untill it gets the video from the server

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your code, with a change and it worked fine - consider using the source element:

```
<video controls>
     <source src="https://video.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Like in my code, sometimes it is working & sometimes not.